# how reshape one part of the data in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~subcateg, ~names,
  "A00", "Kidney failure",
  "A001", "Kidney failure reason1",
  "A002", "Kidney failure reason2",
  "A003", "Kidney failure reason3",
  "B00", "Heart failure",
  "B001", "Heart failure reason1",
  "B002", "Heart failure reason2",
  "B003", "Heart failure reason3",
  "B00", "Lung failure",
  "B001", "Lung failure reason1",
  "B002", "Lung failure reason2",
  "B003", "Lung failure reason3",
)
```

It has categories (3 characters) and subcategories (4 characters) in the same variable, and I need another variable with the category of 3 characters. I would like it to look like this:

```
df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~subcateg, ~names, ~categ, ~names2,
  "A001", "Kidney failure reason1", "A00", "Kidney failure",
  "A002", "Kidney failure reason2","A00", "Kidney failure",
  "A003", "Kidney failure reason3","A00", "Kidney failure",
  "B001", "Heart failure reason1",  "B00", "Heart failure",
  "B002", "Heart failure reason2",  "B00", "Heart failure",
  "B003", "Heart failure reason3",  "B00", "Heart failure",
  "B001", "Lung failure reason1",  "B00", "Lung failure",
  "B002", "Lung failure reason2",  "B00", "Lung failure",
  "B003", "Lung failure reason3",  "B00", "Lung failure",
)
```

Any ideas?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create a grouping variable based on the occurrence of 3 characters (`nchar`) from 'subcateg'), create the 'categ' as the `first` element of 'subcateg', remove the first row (`slice`), and create the 'names2' by removing the `reason` followed by digits substring from the 'names' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = cumsum(nchar(subcateg) == 3)) %>%  
   mutate(categ = first(subcateg)) %>% 
   slice(if(n() == 1) 1 else -1)  %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-grp) %>%
   mutate(names2 = str_remove(names, "\\s+reason\\d+"))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  subcateg names                  categ names2        
  <chr>    <chr>                  <chr> <chr>         
1 A001     Kidney failure reason1 A00   Kidney failure
2 A002     Kidney failure reason2 A00   Kidney failure
3 A003     Kidney failure reason3 A00   Kidney failure
4 B001     Heart failure reason1  B00   Heart failure 
5 B002     Heart failure reason2  B00   Heart failure 
6 B003     Heart failure reason3  B00   Heart failure 
7 B001     Lung failure reason1   B00   Lung failure  
8 B002     Lung failure reason2   B00   Lung failure  
9 B003     Lung failure reason3   B00   Lung failure
```

Comment: this solution was perfect! I still have one issue: I have some categories that doesn't have subcategories. So, I need to keep those that only have 1 observation in the group. For example, imagine the next subcateg is D00,  but there is no 4 chr observation starting with D00. Can I put a condition in the "slice" part to make this work? Thank you!

Comment: @MagdalenaCortina that needs a simple fix.  I added `slice(if(n() == 1) 1 else -1)`

Comment: Perfect! That worked. Do you know how I can paste an "X" at the end of those values of the first column that have only three characters? or in other words, when subcateg=categ, I need to add an X to "subcateg" but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: @MagdalenaCortina Try `mutate(categ = first(subcateg), subcateg = replace(subcateg, 1, str_c(subcateg, "X")))`

Answer (score 0):

If the *lung failure* category begins with C (and not with B) -- is that a mistake? --, another solution is the following:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  separate(subcateg,"categ",sep = "[1-9]", extra = "drop", remove = F) %>% 
  inner_join(df,by=c("categ" = "subcateg"),suffix = c("", "2")) %>% 
  filter(!stringr::str_ends(subcateg,"00")) %>% 
  relocate(categ, .after = names)
```

Comment: thank you! yes! that was a mistake because I was just making up the data. Thanks for this solution!